# How can I refresh data in user variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

How To Refresh User data coming from a variable route? I have a variable called "user" which is coming from a different screen by "react navigation" route that user variable contains all the data I need, So How can I reload that user variable data after "Set follow" is true without fetching anything because "user" variable data is coming is fetching from a different screen?

Code:

```
const Profile = ({ navigation, route }) => {

  const { user } = route.params; // HERE IS THAT USER VAR

  const [issameuser, setIssameuser] = useState(false)
  const [follow, SetFollow] = useState(false)

  const isMyProfile = async (otherprofile) => {
    AsyncStorage.getItem('user').then((loggeduser) => {
      const loggeduserobj = JSON.parse(loggeduser)
      if (loggeduserobj.user.username == otherprofile[0].username) {
        setIssameuser(true)
      }
      else {
        setIssameuser(false)
      }
    })
  }

  const CheckFollow = async (otherprofile) => {
    AsyncStorage.getItem('user')
      .then(loggeduser => {
        const loggeduserobj = JSON.parse(loggeduser);
        return fetch('http://10.0.2.2:3000/checkfollow', {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            followfrom: loggeduserobj.user.username, followto: otherprofile[0].username
          })
        })
      })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        if (data.message == "User in following list") {
          SetFollow(true)
        } else if (data.message == "User not in following list") {
          SetFollow(false)
        } else {
          alert('Please Try Again!')
        }
      })
  }

  const FollowUser = async (otherprofile) => {
    const loggeduser = await AsyncStorage.getItem('user')
    const loggeduserobj = JSON.parse(loggeduser)
    fetch('http://10.0.2.2:3000/Follow', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        followfrom: loggeduserobj.user.username, followto: otherprofile[0].username
      })
    })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        if (data.message == "User Followed") {
          SetFollow(true) // HERE I WANT TO RE-LOAD USER VAR DATA
        }
        else {
          alert("Pleas Try Again")
        }
      })
  }

  

  useEffect(() => {
    isMyProfile(user)
   CheckFollow(user)
  },)
}
```

is their any method to do that or i need to use socketio?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Unfortunately, I don't really follow your question. Could you please rewrite your question while keeping the focus on the technical problem?

Comment: @Chris Yep! How can I reload the user variable data? this is my quastion

Comment: Your functions are all async, but you're not using them asynchronously... you should at least be `await`ing those promises.

Comment: @JeffMercado Yep my bad but How can I reload the user variable data